# How to publish sdf file in moveit2?

Tags: ros2, moveit, robotic-arm, sdformat, planning-scene

I am using ros2 humble with gazebo fortress.
I want to publish a plannig scene(/planning scene world, not sure which topic)in the moveit2. I have a sdf file of the world which includes some objects, but not robot model.

so my question is that, is it possible to publish a planning scene from sdf file? if yes, how can i do it?